# A question on the intuition of decomposition of the element of symmetry group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Any element of symmetry group $S_{n}$ can be decomposed as products of transpositions. Any m-cycle can be decomposed as m-1 transposition products. How should I think of this decomposition? Is there any intuitive way of thinking this decomposition without memorizing the formula of decomposition or is there an intuitive way to derive the decomposition formula? I knew from the book the formula for decomposition was given explicitly.

Comment: I mean, it's just instructions for the permutation by breaking it up into steps of switching only two elements at a time (a painful way to perform a permutation). It's just useful to know you have it in practice for some proofs, and if you're in computer science it's sort of comforting to know you can use logic gates to move bits into whatever order, but I've never found the characterization to be all that deep.

Comment: See this [link](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math47aF08/M47F08Note09aa.pdf) for a nice diagramatic discussion of the cycle decomposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $m$ pieces of paper labelled $1$, $2$, $3$, … $m$. Place them on the table in the following order: 
$$m,1,2,3,4,5,…,m-2,m-1
$$
That represents an $m$-cycle. Now, how do you put them back in order? First transpose $m$ and $1$:
$$1,m,2,3,4,5,…,m-2,m-1
$$
Next transpose $m$ and $2$:
$$1,2,m,3,4,5,…,m-2,m-1
$$
Next transpose $m$ and $3$:
$$1,2,3,m,4,5,…,m-2,m-1
$$
And so on… after $m-2$ of these transpositions you get to
$$1,2,3,4,5,…,m-2,m,m-1
$$
And one last transposition, the $m-1$st one: transpose $m$ and $m-1$:
$$1,2,3,4,5,…,m-2,m-1,m
$$